# Make Steam requests using Python via Tor

Tags: python, python-requests, steam, tor

My code:

```
import requests
def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session
session = get_tor_session()
print(session.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=#p1_popular_desc').status_code)
```

Status code 429 steam does not suit me,
if I change the link to google.com then the status code is 200.
How to make status code 200 for Steam?

Comment: 429 indicates they are rate limiting the exit node because steam is getting too much traffic from it. They may also just be blocking crawlers.

Comment: if I use requests.get instead of session.get then the status code is 200, but I need to use tor

Comment: @jordanm with much server, you can avoid `429` with sending a `User-Agent` to the host.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks4://116.193.218.18:34344',
    'https': 'socks4://116.193.218.18:34344'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'}


def Tor():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(
            "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=#p1_popular_desc", proxies=proxies)
        return r.status_code


print(Tor())
```

Output:

```
200
```